# pmd import: Entry[import from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

Tags: java, maven, plugins, pmd, rule

I am trying to add a custom rule written in java language to the pmd maven plugin.
I expected everything to work fine when executing pmd:check goal from IntelliJ 2016.3.2 Community Edition, but instead I get the following message.

execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-pmd-plugin:3.9.0:pmd (pmd) on project pmd-custom-rule-use: Execution pmd of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-pmd-plugin:3.9.0:pmd failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-pmd-plugin:3.9.0:pmd: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.sourceforge.pmd.renderers.AbstractRenderer.(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
--- here goes some of my .m2 jars listings ---
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

The configuration of the plugin is

```
   <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.codingtogo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>pmd-custom-rule</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <rulesets>
                    <ruleset>/myCustomRules/myRuleSet.xml</ruleset>
                </rulesets>
                <sourceEncoding>utf-8</sourceEncoding>
                <targetJdk>1.7</targetJdk>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*Bean.java</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/generated/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <excludeRoots>
                    <excludeRoot>target/generated-sources/stubs</excludeRoot>
                </excludeRoots>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The ruleset xml file is like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ruleset name="My custom rules"
     xmlns="http://pmd.sf.net/ruleset/1.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://pmd.sf.net/ruleset/1.0.0    
http://pmd.sf.net/ruleset_xml_schema.xsd"



xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://pmd.sf.net/ruleset_xml_schema.xsd">
<rule name="WhileLoopsMustUseBracesRule"
      message="Avoid using 'while' statements without curly braces"
      class="com.codingtogo.WhileLoopsMustUseBracesRule">
    <description>
        Avoid using 'while' statements without using curly braces
    </description>
    <priority>3</priority>

    <example>
        <![CDATA[
        public void doSomething() {
          while (true)
              x++;
        }
    ]]>
    </example>
</rule>
</ruleset>
```

The dependency of the plugin is the jar where the class referenced in the ruleset is defined. The pom configuration of that project is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0       
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.codingtogo</groupId>
<artifactId>pmd-custom-rule</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.pmd/pmd -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.pmd</groupId>
        <artifactId>pmd</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
   </build>
 </project>
```

And the class source code is

```
package com.codingtogo;

import net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTWhileStatement;

public class WhileLoopsMustUseBracesRule {
public Object visit(ASTWhileStatement node, Object data) {
    System.out.println("hello world");
    return data;
}
}
```

If I take the dependency from my jar from the pmd maven plugin out, then it runs and produces the error
[ERROR] Error instantiating a rule
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.codingtogo.WhileLoopsMustUseBracesRule

and the build is successful. I pinpoint it because the initial error was an api incompatibility problem but, if I take the dependency from my jar out, then the api incompatibility error is gone.

Thanks in advance :)

--- EDIT [SOLVED] ---
The problem was that I was using the wrong dependency as pointed out by @Johnco. Also, I was using the wrong classes. This is the final setup.

```
package com.codingtogo;
import net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTWhileStatement;
import net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.rule.AbstractJavaRule;

public class WhileLoopsMustUseBracesRule extends AbstractJavaRule {
    public Object visit(ASTWhileStatement node, Object data) {
        System.out.println("hello world");
        return data;
    }
}
```

Note the extends class is now AbstractJavaRule and not AbstractRule.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.pmd</groupId>
        <artifactId>pmd-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: So, a few comments... Firstly, your rule's dependency on pmd should be `<scope>runtime</scope>`, as the PMD version is set from the consumer side, not the rule. Also, you should consider upgrading to PMD 6.2.0 (and the maven plugin 3.9.0). Prior to 6.0 the classloader wasn't properly isolated, which caused some problems very similar to the one your describe (see https://github.com/pmd/pmd/pull/680).

Comment: Thank you so much. I was using the wrong dependency. I will update the description to show the solution.

Comment: See also https://github.com/pmd/pmd-examples/tree/master/custom-rule-with-maven for an example.